Implementation of a state space controller
I have recently learned about state space modelling along with LQR. I am interested in building a small project where I can implement a state space controller. I know how to design and get the kalman filter gain along with the state feedback regulator gains I'm unsure how to implement this controller physically. Can anyone help? How do I start?
Edit1: I have a aero-pendulum setup where I would like to control the angle of the pendulum. I can model it in Matlab as having 2 state, instantaneous angular position and velocity. I can measure the angular position and can estimate the velocity using a full order state observer.If I want to design a state space controller for physically demonstrating the aero-pendulum setup, what kind of sensors would I need? I believe I will also need a microcontroller so how must i proceed

Your question is unclear, and you need to edit your question.  It sounds like you currently have nothing built physically, and you're asking how to go from nothing to a complete control system demonstrator.  Is this correct? If so -- say so in the question.  While you're editing, tell us what an aero-pendulum is (I know what I'd call "aero-pendulum", but I don't know if that's what you have).  Also tell us your budget, and whether you want an assembly that'll last a few weeks or for years.

There are ready made hardware kits for control system learning some of which include inverted-pendulum experiment hardware. Some of those kits require the controller to be coded in a micro controller (which is usually included in the kit). some of the kits have plugins to Simulink which will automatically detect and connect the controller block diagram in Simulink, to the kit hardware connected to the PC. Search the web to see the kits available in your country.
